# Cloudpickle.dump(pyspark_Alsmodel_object),getting error py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-sagemaker

After creating ALS model object,using pyspark.

Sample code example:

```
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.recommendation import ALS
from pyspark.sql import Row

lines = spark.read.text("data/mllib/als/sample_movielens_ratings.txt").rdd
parts = lines.map(lambda row: row.value.split("::"))
ratingsRDD = parts.map(lambda p: Row(userId=int(p[0]), movieId=int(p[1]),
                                     rating=float(p[2]), timestamp=long(p[3])))
ratings = spark.createDataFrame(ratingsRDD)
(rating_data, test) = ratings.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2])

# Build the recommendation model using ALS on the training data
# Note we set cold start strategy to 'drop' to ensure we don't get NaN evaluation metrics
als = ALS(maxIter=5, regParam=0.01, userCol="userId", itemCol="movieId", ratingCol="rating",
          coldStartStrategy="drop")

    als_model = als_spec.fit(rating_data)
```

here i am just creating ALS model and making cloudepickel.
if we are using fit then also need to do transform?

I am trying pickel the my als_model object using the below code :

```
with open(os.path.join(model_path, 'als-als-model.pkl'), 'w') as out:
                cloudpickle.dump(als_model, out)
```

I am getting error like below:

```
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 324, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name, value))
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o224.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
#011at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
#011at 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-8c94f4ee0de9> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 tree.fit(data_location)

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py in fit(self, inputs, wait, logs, job_name)
    152         self.latest_training_job = _TrainingJob.start_new(self, inputs)
    153         if wait:
--> 154             self.latest_training_job.wait(logs=logs)
    155         else:
    156             raise NotImplemented('Asynchronous fit not available')
```

Comment: can you provide more informations? I guess you are missing transform line

Comment: Hi Ramesh,i am creating a Dataframe by loading the input text file,after that " als_spec = ALS().setMaxIter(spec['max_itter']).setRegParam(spec['reg_param']) \
            .setUserCol('user_id') \
            .setItemCol('item_id') \
            .setRank(spec['als_rank']) \
            .setRatingCol('rating')" ,next i am executing the above code

Comment: what I meant is that you are missing `transformed = als_model.transform(rating_data)` part

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-collaborative-filtering.html

Comment: i am following above als pyspark example .here i am just creating ALS model and making cloudepickel.

Comment: good luck with your implementation then. :) I can be of no help beyond that

Comment: Thanks,last question  from my side ,is there any way to serialize dataframe  in pyspark  ?

Comment: they are already serializable. Thats the reason you can do groupby and aggregations . Shuffling of data happens due to serialization nature of dataframes. And without serialization property, distributed system is not possible. serialization is the backbone of communication between nodes